# Is it safe to open a message in inbox? (but not the GIF itself?)

Tags: malware, virus, facebook

I received message in my inbox of facebook which says my friend *sent me a gif*.
Now, is it safe if I **only** see the message? By seeing the message I mean "just" the message itself, and not click on the "gif". is it safe?
Or it is not possible to safely open such a message?
I am concerned about virus.

Comment: facebook is probably more harmful than the attachment.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you concerned about malware? A GIF is just a image format, which may contain animations. It's rather old, and the code is fairly well tested, so there's quite low chances of security problems in gif handling code.

Furthermore Facebook is quite good at filtering out malicious content - especially in messages.

In sum: the chances of getting malware from viewing a image on the internet is next to zero. The chances of getting malware from clicking on something in a message on Facebook, **without** further action, such as downloading files, is low.

Note that FB Messenger also supports gifs from a approved palette. In case it is one of those gifs, it's absolutely safe.

Comment: +1 However, `clicking on something in a message` is a bit of a different story since, say, a link to an external image doesn't actually have lead to an image.

Comment: @Arminius true, but facebook are rather good at filtering out suspicious URLs, and to follow up on that logic, you basically have to stop using the WWW. To some extent you have to trust your browser not to run random binary files it comes across without asking you first... Unless you actually do download and run a file, modern browsers are fairly good at avoiding this.